# Oracle APEX 5 Classic Report's CSV Export Issue

Tags: oracle, google-chrome, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

Oracle APEX page with classic report redirects to blank page with following message after CSV download completes.

```
wwv_flow.show?p_flow_id=207&p_flow_step_id=11&p_instance=11672320678093&p_debug=&p_request=FLOW_EXCEL_OUTPUT_R330325816060382028_en
```

Although this issue is only occurring in Chrome browser version 75 and APEX version 5, it is working fine in APEX 4.2 and Chrome 75.

I am using this attribute of Classic Report to download CSV,

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem,
and found myself replacing the JS behind the "download" link. instead of using window.location.href="" I have apex.navigation.redirect(...)
original:

```
<a href='javascript:window.location.href=apex.server.pluginUrl("SC95h...);'>Download</a>
```

updated:

```
<a href='javascript:apex.navigation.redirect(apex.server.pluginUrl("SC95h...));'>Download</a>
```

the short js doing the replacement (STATIC_ID is the static id for the report):

```
var loc = 'javascript:window.location.href=',
navi = 'javascript:apex.navigation.redirect(';

$('div#STATIC_ID div.t-Report-links a')[0].href = 
$('div#STATIC_ID div.t-Report-links a')[0].href.replace('});','}));').replace(loc,navi);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug - see this [APEX forum question](https://community.oracle.com/thread/4276930).   The bug is fixed for APEX 18.2 and over, or there is a workaround is Hilary Farrell's response there:

> In the region footer, add the following HTML markup in order to get a
>   "custom download link"
>
> ```
> <a href="f?p=&APP_ID.:&APP_PAGE_ID.:&SESSION.:FLOW_EXCEL_OUTPUT_R18960266605696647390_en">Download</a>
> ```

(You would need to adjust the region ID.)